# FireDacFBDriver not found

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

When creating a new Rad Server Package as a Data Module with DataBase Endpoints for a Firebird 3.0 database it fails to compile with the error FireDACFBDriver not found.

I have found a work around by removing FireDacFBDriver.dcp from the required section of the project, recompiling and it asks to add the FireDacIBDriver, which seems to work.

I searched the Embarcadero install directory and there is no FireDacFBDriver.dcp and I am wondering if it is something that was intended to include but was not distributed.

Is it available?

```
type
  [ResourceName('Blob')]
  TBlobResource1 = class(TDataModule)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    qryTABLE: TFDQuery;
    [ResourceSuffix('Test')]
    dsrTABLE: TEMSDataSetResource;

  published
  end;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterResource(TypeInfo(TBlobResource1));
end;

initialization
  Register;
end.
```

Comment: I guess that is a bug in the RAD Server Package wizard. They probably just use the driver ID to concatenate the DCP file name, which fails for Firebird. Please file a bugreport in Quality Portal.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a TFDPhysFBDriverLink and configure it. Configuration information can be found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.DriverID

Comment: I doubt that this would magically make a file named FireDacFBDriver.dcp appear from nowhere.

Comment: I tried that with no effect. I think I would agree that it is a bug

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is a bug and will report in the Quality Portal. If I get a different response, I will update. The Workaround is to delete FireDacFBDriver from the required files and recompile adding in recommended FireDacIBDriver.